# Roam array of arrays by position in Python

Tags: python

I have this array of arrays:

```
A = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

And I want to convert it to have an array like this (having an array with 1st elements, next array with 2nd elements, ...):

```
AUX = [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

I've tried with

```
for i in A:
   for j in i:
      #code
```

But with that I'm just getting the sequence of the original array `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `zip` to transpose the array:

```
result = [list(x) for x in zip(*A)]
```

If you're using Numpy you can just use the transpose function:

```
result = np.transpose(np.array(A))
result = np.array(A).T  # equivalent
```

Answer (score 1):

You should to use the zip function in the following way:

```
AUX = [list(x) for x in zip(*A)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried a begineer Friendly way

```
A = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
AUX = []
n = 0
while n != len(A):
    AUX.append([i[n] for i in A])
    n = n + 1
```